# Why is this happening to my screen?

Tags: windows-10, display

Take a look at the screenshots below:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Do you know what might be the cause of that?

**EDIT**
Some more info:

1. It happens everywhere no matter if I have a window open or not.
2. For some reason, it won't happen inside the LoL game **unless** I change the volume (which in Windows 10 produces that top-left animation of the volume changing). It will though happen in LoL's pre- and after- (a game) screen.
3. My pc crashes with or without a blue screen **too** much with different error codes on the blue screen each time.

**UPDATE**
After following LPChip's advice in the comments (and removing 2 out of 3 ram sticks) the problem is no longer present, so it's most certainly a faulty ram.

Comment: Does it only happen in your browser? Does it happen in other browsers? does it happen outside of a browser?

Comment: @LPChip it happens everywhere, but I have noticed that it happens (mostly and worse) when something uses a lot of ram. Also my internet research says it is probably a faulty ram, but I want to be sure before upgrading any hardware.

Comment: @LPChip for some reason though, it won't happen inside the League of Legends game, but it will happen in its pre- and after- screen.

Comment: Sounds like its your RAM indeed. If you have 2 sticks of ram, take one stick out and see if the problem remains, if so, put it back in, and take the other one out to see if it remains or not. If the problem is still there, you can safely say your ram is fine.

Comment: Also, please post a few of the BSoD stop codes. They will really help determining where things go wrong.

Comment: I will keep track of them from now on, but one I can remember was something like KMODE_HANDLE_etcetc. Also, I have 3 sticks of ram (:P) could that be the problem?

Comment: No, 3 sticks is fine. Just pull 2 out and only keep one, see if the problem still exists, if so, remove that stick and put the other 2 back in and test again.

Comment: I did what you said and the problem is "almost" gone with one stick inside. I say almost because those lines don't appear anymore and everything is fine, but it's not optimal which I guess happens because I am running on 2GBs of ram right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment exchange, we concluded that the problem is indeed one or two broken RAM chips.

You now want to exchange the RAM chips until you load the system with just 1 RAM stick, and the problems return.

Then take it out, put the other 2 RAM chips in and see if the pc remains stable. If so, replace the broken RAM stick with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Those artifacts could be due to your video card overheating/dying, or it could simply be the browser not rendering the page correctly.

I'd suggest making sure your video card isn't full of dust, the fan is running correctly, and isn't getting really hot some other way.

If your screen returns to normal after you minimize and restore the window, it could just be the browser.  It if happens to other apps, check your video card.

Edit: If you upgraded your video card device drivers recently, try rolling them back to see if it becomes more stable.